# Running VNC from Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, vnc

I am running a docker container that starts a vnc server. I launch it with:

```
docker run --rm -ti -p 5900:5900 rosdocker:latest
```

Is there a way, or how do I, control the virtual display resolution? Nothing I've read mentions it, and it seems to be 1024x768 according to the display settings int the Ubuntu gui. Is there a way to change it or is it hardwired somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `rosdocker` image is based on "dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc" and you keep its entrypoint.

when launching the container, you can use env `RESOLUTION=1920x1080` to set the resolution.

Or if my assumption is wrong, add the following to your entrypoint script.

```
if [ -n "$RESOLUTION" ]; then
    sed -i "s/1024x768/$RESOLUTION/" /usr/local/bin/xvfb.sh
fi
```